# how to adding framework7 in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, html-framework-7

How can I use `framework7` in `ionic2` project?

I install `framework7` in the my `ionic2` project:

```
npm i framework7 --save
```

What I want to do is to add the `typescript` definition to the project from [this link](https://github.com/JasonKleban/Framework7.d.ts)

But I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually copy the file or use a tool like [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings).

```
typings install framework7=github:JasonKleban/Framework7.d.ts/framework7.d.ts#e31bad1d988d0471e2edcd17d8fa1fbf6d3a62b8/ --global --save
```

You could also open up an issue to the author to contribute the file to DefinitelyTyped.